# Laravel 5 - __callStatic function is working correctly?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a model extended from Model its name is IcerikRltCategory and i want to use getTable function with staticly. But __callStatic function does not fire anything. Because not entered this magic function scope.

Error message is:

> 1/1
>   ErrorException in ContentController.php line 51:
>   Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::getTable() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getTable` method requires an instance of the model object to work. The method itself look like this:

```
public function getTable()
{
    if (isset($this->table)) return $this->table;

    return str_replace('\\', '', snake_case(str_plural(class_basename($this))));
}
```

And as you can see it uses [`$this`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) to access the property, which means in needs context given by an object instance. So calling the method statically won't work:

```
IcerikRltCategory::getTable(); // this won't work
```

However when you have an instance, it will:

```
$model = new IcerikRltCategory();
$model->getTable(); // this will work
```

Comment: Thanks for reply i didn't think enter the function. I understand and inside of the getTable() function must be work with static variables.